# How can I ensure Maven uses the appropriate snapshot version used by one of my dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

Project "P" has a dependency on Project "X" version LATEST. X has a dependency on jar "A" version LATEST.

When I build project P, it will pull down the correct (LATEST) version of X which is currently a jar. But when it attempts to build X, I'm assuming Maven will realize that X is dependent on jar A, and will attempt to acquire A.

I want to enforce that while building P, that acquiring and building X will pull down the version of A that was used by X when X published itself to the repository. I don't want to pull down the LATEST version of A that might be newer than the time X published itself to the repository.

I'm thinking there are multiple ways to address this scenario. I have the feeling that building X as a .war is one of them. (I have control of project X and can build that as a .war if required), but I'm happy to hear other proposals. If X is a .war and has the version of A that it used when the .war is built, will Maven attempt to check if there is a newer version of A, when P is attempting to build?

Answer (score 0):

If X did not lock down the version of A it depends on, then without further disambiguation by you it will use the absolute latest version of A in central. You can explicitly specify a version of A yourself, but there's no such thing as "Use what was previously the latest A."

Since you say you have control of project X, you should release a new version of X which specifies the **exact** version of A you require. Snapshot dependencies in Maven are a serious antipattern.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying -- though I'll need to figure out how to have an automated way of X specifying A's version in X's POM. These projects are for automated testing and X is built daily, and intentionally needs A's latest, (that's part of the test), but X only publishes itself if its tests pass. If I can automate X updating it's POM with the version # for A that it used, then this would work. I'll look into that.

Comment: I'm not following. X is entirely auto-generated? Or it's a project consisting entirely of tests for A? It sounds like X and A should be one project.

Comment: Hi Tom, difficult to explain here, but suffice to say that it's a CI environment and we have a need for them to be separate. Looking in to this a bit more, it seems like the 'versions' plugin can help automatically update the POM of X to bind it to the version of A that it used.. looks promising.

Comment: That may solve your problem, however it sounds like in general Maven is not a good fit for you. Dynamically changing dependencies is a pretty smelly anti-pattern in the Maven world (even -SNAPSHOT dependencies are frowned on) so you may find more problems moving forward. Some more background would help.

Comment: Any references with details on why snapshot dependencies are antipattern and frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept of snapshots revolve around timestamps. SO if a new snapshot version is available while building then it will be downloaded. 
Only option is to build in offline mode but i would discourage that.

Another approach , you can include all dependant projects in your workspace and add dependency of these projects in you main project. Now maven will not download jars for these, it will refer to files in these projects.